# Repeatedly Change Index in DataFrames In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes:

df1 :

```
ip  name
```

df2 :

```
name country
```

df3:

```
country city
```

I have to match them by IP. What is correct way to do this? We match them df1 and df2 and then match result of df1 and df2 with df3 with index change. I think that ist not correct way.

Comment: Can you add some data samples? Are data in columns duplicated?

Comment: I think columns `ip`, `name` and `country`

Comment: @jezrael yes there is so many duplicated data

Comment: Then input sample data with desired output are really necesary, please add duplicates to columns. Duplicates obviously dont like `merge`, but I think there are some possible solutions for it.

Comment: @jezrael I'm looking for this solution

Comment: Do you think answer bellow?

Comment: yes but I have duplicated items

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need double [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), parameter `on` should me omit if only same joined columns of `df`s:

```
df = df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)
```

Comment: I have to create df4 : name ip country city dataframe. Like comparison